# How To Fetch sessionId using IronPython script in Spotfire?

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I'm building a customized log for my Spotfire dashboard and would like to know if there is a way of getting the sessionId (the one we get in the actionlog log) using IronPython.

Thanks

Comment: are you aware of the Spotfire Action Log? this might cover your needs...

Comment: Hi @niko, thanks for the reply. I'm already using the Spotfire Action Log, but would like to get the Sessionid for my custom log in order to "merge" the information from both.

Comment: yikes, yeah you literally wrote that in the question xD. I did some digging and it doesn't look like the python API exposes anything for the web player session ID. however, since you can add javascript code to a textarea, I'd suggest to investigate that route and then pass that value back into IP